# Composer updates a dependency to an older version

Tags: php, composer-php

I regularly run `composer update` in my project and then check what dependencies were updated. But today I noticed a strange output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.4.0 => 0.3.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (3.2.0 => 3.2.1): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
```

You can see that the phpdocumentor/type-resolver package was downgraded from 0.4.0 to 0.3.0, though the command was `update`.
Is it normal or a bug or whatever?

Comment: can you include `-vvv` to update?

Comment: You need to delete the composer.lock file then try running update command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've found the answer. It is in this commit: [Downgrade phpdocumentor/type-resolver to 0.3](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/ReflectionDocBlock/commit/48d3720bf476a293bdc5df3b3a4a70fa74a1fa2f)

`In order to restore a bc break made in 3.2.0 I downgraded the
type-resolver. This makes the version less compatible with php 7.1
But will help our users to upgrade.`

Indeed phpdocumentor/type-resolver is a dependency of phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock and its maintainer deliberately downgraded the type-resolver. So everything's normal. And it's not a composer bug. It was just the first time I saw such a behavior, that's why I found it strange.